# Have WOTC published any combined magic item tables?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have bought all the various DnD source books and so have access to a whole array of magic item tables as a DM.

Have WOTC published any combined random magic item tables simialir to the ones in the PHB but that combine all the available magic items across the various sourcebooks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The best we have from Wizard’s is the tables in *Xanathar’s Guide*.

The magic item tables from *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* include the magic items printed therein as well as the magic items from the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*:

> The tables in this section classify the magic items from the Dungeon Master’s Guide and the new items presented here into minor items and major items, then separate the items in each group according to rarity. Each table entry includes the item’s type and an indication of whether the item requires attunement. Artifacts aren’t included here; they are beyond even major items in power and importance.

Other than this, there are no tables in any of the printed books that consolidate items from multiple books.